# How to create a rectangle in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Am very lost on how to make a rectangle or object that can be seen in the panel. Currently have the below code but is only giving a background color. I am unsure how to call the paintComponent method or the repaint in this scenario.

```
public class myProject extends JPanel {

    public final int WIDTH= 1000, HEIGHT= 1000;
    public Rectangle user;
    public static myProject myProject;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myProject= new myProject();
        myProject.start();

    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame main= new JFrame("Main");
        JPanel game= new JPanel();
        main.add(game);
        main.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setVisible(true);

        JLabel welcome= new JLabel("Welcome");
        welcome.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        welcome.
        game.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        game.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JButton startButton= new JButton("Start");
        startButton.setFont(startButton.getFont().deriveFont(20.0f));

        startButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        startButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> startClicked());
        game.add(startButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        startButton.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void repaint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 50, WIDTH, 50);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(user.x, user.y, user.width, user.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 40);
    }

    public void startClicked() {
        System.out.println("Game Started");
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I am unsure how to call the paintComponent method"* - You don't.  The paint system will call your paint components when it decides something needs to be update, this is a passive update workflow, as a paint pass may be triggered for any number of reasons at any time.  You can request a paint pass by calling `repaint` on your component, but it's still update to the paint sub system to decide what and when a paint pass will take place. `repaint(Graphics g)` is badly named, how ever, you'd have to call it from within the `paintComponent` method

Comment: I would recommend looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details about how paint works and how you should work with

Comment: You might also like to have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for switching between views

Answer (score 3):

> I am unsure how to call the paintComponent method

You don't.  The paint sub system will call your component's "paint" methods when it decides something needs to be update, this is a passive update workflow, as a paint pass may be triggered for any number of reasons at any time.

You can request a paint pass by calling `repaint` on your component, but it's still up to the paint sub system to decide what and when a paint pass will take place. `repaint(Graphics g)` is badly named, however, you'd have to call it from within the `paintComponent` method.

I would recommend looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details about how paint works and how you should work with.

You might also like to have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for switching between views.

The following example uses a `Overlayout` so that I can "overlay" the menu over the top the game, and basically acts as a "pause" like state.

It makes use of a "delegate" to allow the menu/game change the state accordingly, but without actually needing to know about each other.

It makes use of [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to animate the position of the box across the screen. The nice thing about this is that it can be easily started and stopped

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public interface Controller {
            public void startGame();
            public void pauseGame();
        }

        private GamePane gamePane;
        private MenuPane menuPane;
        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));

            Controller controller = new Controller() {
                @Override
                public void startGame() {
                    menuPane.setVisible(false);
                    gamePane.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void pauseGame() {
                    menuPane.setVisible(true);
                    gamePane.stop();
                }
            };

            gamePane = new GamePane(controller);
            menuPane= new MenuPane(controller);

            add(menuPane);
            add(gamePane);
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {
        private MainPane.Controller controller;
        public MenuPane(MainPane.Controller controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(label, gbc);

            JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
            add(startButton, gbc);

            startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    controller.startGame();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 192));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {
        private MainPane.Controller controller;
        private Timer timer;
        private Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
        public GamePane(MainPane.Controller controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
            setBackground(Color.RED);

            box.y = (800 - box.height) / 2;

            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                private int xDelta = 1;
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    box.x += xDelta;
                    box.y = (getHeight() - box.height) / 2;
                    if (box.x < 0) {
                        box.x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (box.x + box.width > getWidth()) {
                        box.x = getWidth() - box.width;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    controller.pauseGame();
                }
            });
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(box);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, obviously, if you want to control more then one object, you will need to maintain the individual states of those objects and access them from something like `List`

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I'm still struggling with my code however and was wondering if you knew why I can't seem to draw any rectangles on the GUI.

Comment: The `game` panel is occupying the full space of the window and `myProject` is never added to anything